# How do I rotate a gluCynlinder in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

For context, I'm trying to model a simple 1x1 lego brick in OpenGL. I setup my camera to look at the origin and 'up' is in the Y direction. I'm trying to draw a cylinder for the little nub on the cube, and cannot figure out how to rotate it. C++ code:

```
//draw cylinder
glPushMatrix();
glTranslated(0.0, 0.4 , 0.0);
//glRotatef(angle, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   
GLUquadricObj * qobj = gluNewQuadric();
gluCylinder(qobj, 0.24, 0.24, 0.18, 16, 16);
glPopMatrix();
```

I'm trying to rotate it around the x axis by 90 degrees but glRotatef doesn't appear to do anything, or just makes the whole thing disappear. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked well for me:

```
glPushMatrix();
GLUquadricObj * qobj = gluNewQuadric();
glTranslated(0.0, 0.4 , 0.0);
glRotatef(angle * 10, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);   
gluCylinder(qobj, 1.24, 1.24, 1.18, 16, 16);
gluDeleteQuadric(qobj);
glPopMatrix();
```

No matter which order of *glRotate* and *glTranslate* i've used.

Comment: I changed the ordering to something closer to this and it worked better. I still run into the problem where nothing is drawn initially, and then the cylinder pops up when I hit one of the camera controls...

Comment: Nope. The control flow is the issue. You need to

- create the quadric object once, before all rendering,
- call the remaining functions (from glPushMatrix to glPopMatrix) every frame.

Comment: I think that this is camera problem for sure - "nothing is drawn initially, and then the cylinder pops up when I hit one of the camera controls". I can assume that camera doesn't points cylinder from the start.

Comment: @shybovycha: are you, perhaps running this under Windows Vista or 7? I've seen some problems with output from OpenGL not showing up initially, but when re-drawng, it suddenly shows up -- but if you disable the DWM (Desktop Window Manager), it all works perfectly.

Comment: @Jerry My system was Win7 x64. Now i'm under Ubuntu and if you want i can test your code =)

Comment: I'm running on Mac OS X. It's fixed enough now that I can work through it I think.